# HP printer drivers for Lubuntu

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, printing

On one of my old computers, I have Lubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

My OS can not find drivers for HP Envy 4526 printer.

What can I do? I am not able to print for the moment (thought the printer is recognized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the solution of @N0rbert but I got errors when trying to run `hp-setup` utility. So I ended up by adding the printer via the web interface instead: (`http://127.0.0.1:631/`). This worked for me.

P.S. 
There is a main step before reaching this one (and which is not covered by my question, of course) and it consists in installing the [Common UNIX Printing System](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html) by running:
 `sudo apt install cups`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should install `hplip-gui` package with `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` and add your printer from here.

According to HP page Envy 4520 Series [are fully supported](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) since 3.15.1 (16.04 LTS xenial has 3.16.3+repack0-1).

After installation you can launch HP utility from terminal as `hp-toolbox` or from GUI as *HPLIP Toolbox*.

Answer (score 0):

## Search it

You will need to get drivers for this printer... With this being said, After performing a quick search on "HP Envy 4526 printer Linux drivers," I was able to find some drivers here [Here](https://drivershp.net/hp-envy-4520-all-in-one-printer-series-drivers-download/)... With this being said, it looks like you have to again choose your printer then choose your drivers... Then they should download and most likely they have you run something like:

`dpkg -i driver_Name_here`

And then finally they should be all setup!

Good luck

Comment: @N0rbert... Updated link